# How to specify relations using SQLAlchemy declarative syntax?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I can't find any proper documentation on how to specify relations
using the declarative syntax of SQLAlchemy.. Is it unsupported? That is, should I use the "traditional" syntax?
I am looking for a way to specify relations at a higher level, avoiding having to mess with foreign keys etc.. I'd like to just declare "addresses = OneToMany(Address)" and let the framework handle the details.. I know that Elixir can do that, but I was wondering if "plain" SQLA could do it too.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "That is, should I use the "traditional" syntax?"  Please elaborate.

Comment: Well, I am looking for a way to specify relations at a higher level, so avoiding messing with foreign keys etc.. I'd like to just declare "addresses = OneToMany(Address)" and let the framework handle the details.. I know that Elixir can do that, but I was wondering if "plain" SQLA could do it too.

Comment: @Joril: would you please update the question with your comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to [the declarative plugin](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/04/plugins.html#plugins_declarative), where everything I am about to say is documented with examples:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    addresses = relation("Address", backref="user")

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'addresses'

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

Comment: So, no way to avoid manually creating foreign keys, junction tables and the like.. :( (aside from using Elixir of course) Thanks!

Comment: No, the relation function can do anything that you can do with SQLA. More powerful than elixir probably.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the "Configuring Relations" section of the [Declarative docs](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/reference/ext/declarative.html).  Not quite as high level as "OneToMany" but better than fully specifying the relation.

```
class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'addresses'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(50))
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the updated link :) But.. I'm sorry, I can't see the difference with what Ali A said.. ^^; Given that Address class, you still have to specificy an "address=relation(...)" inside User.. Am I missing something? ^^;

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood your question!  Yes, to get it both ways, then I think you do have to do that amount of specification. Ask on the SA list (where Mike Bayer answers, settling all disputes!), if you want a more authoritative answer!